# Ben Gardner's eye in Jaws

Tags: jaws

In Spielberg's classic *Jaws* there is a scene when Hooper and Brody find Ben (they'll wish their fathers had never met their mothers), Garndner's boat floating apparently abandoned. When Hooper goes to look at the hull and finds the shark tooth, Ben's head floats down scaring Hooper into dropping the tooth, however Ben is missing an eye. I don't know how Ben dies, be it drowning or whatever, but how does he manage to lose and eye?

Comment: Not entirely sure - but there are a lot of scavenger species in the ocean. Could be a crab or something ate the eye

Comment: @HorusKol I get your point but the incident must have happened recent to the discovery of the boat (a few hours at most) and how could a crab get onto the boat?

Comment: I know you're looking for an in-universe reason, however there likely isn't one. the screenplay specifically mentions eyes in Gardner's detached head. When it was decided to make the fake head, it may have been a decision on the day to go for even further effect or the fake eye could also have simply fallen out of the head.

Comment: @CGCampbell thanks. Never read the book so not sure If character appears there. I know the actor was actually a local who Spielberg and co found funny and used him for that reason. Think 'it just looks cool' strikes again!

Answer (score 1):

When the boat crashed outside of Amity, the impact of the shark hitting the boat may have caused Ben Gardner to fall over, and he could have simply had bad luck and knocked his eye out on a sharp edge or a fishhook. Or, there is always the thought of underwater creatures picking parts off of his body. Hope this helps.